# Alternative To Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js, visual-studio-2017

Is there a web version of Visual Studio Community ?
I am working on a ASP.Net web project in C# and JS knockout using Entity Framework to connect to a  SQL database

My code is in GIT but I would like to be able to edit, develop and run the project by connecting via a web browser on an Android tablet

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As of Today (December 2018) that's not possible.

You could use a Remote Desktop and connect to it to do the coding though...

Comment: Although- You could test the code using [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io) or something of the sort and edit the code with a text editor. Although, without a good IDE, it sounds like a nightmare. I'm not sure the extent of SharpLab either. I've never had a need for it, just know of it.